# How to delegate a dll callback function

Tags: c#, vb.net, dllimport

I need your help.
I'm trying to read a mifare card using sdk in dll file. I set the device to auto read once a card tapped.
The below is the sdk reference about AutoRead

```
int SetOnAutoRead(TOnAutoRead aEventFun)
```

**aEventFun**   a callback function. Once reader have read data, data will be sent to PC, and then the
callback function will be called with passing data in hex string format (standard C
string), The callback function have the definition:

```
typedef int (__stdcall *TOnAutoRead)(char *HexDataRead);
```

**Return** 0x00 – Successful (Refer the API return code for other values)'
**Description** Set a callback function, it will be called automatically once reader have read card after you call API AutoRead_Run(), it let you know when and what dat

I've tried to write in VB Net code as below :

```vb
Public Delegate Function TOnAutoRead_Delegate(ByRef pData As Byte) As Integer

Public Declare Function SetOnAutoRead Lib "CVAPIV01_DESFire.dll" (ByVal f As TOnAutoRead_Delegate) As Integer
```

Usage :

```vb
Dim fp As TOnAutoRead_Delegate = AddressOf TOnAutoRead
status = SetOnAutoRead(fp)

Public Shared Function TOnAutoRead(ByRef pData As Byte) As Integer
    MsgBox(pData.ToString)
End Function
```

When I tapped the card, nothing happened and no error was occurred.

Please help me to solve this. I got frustated  for these days.
You may help me in C#, I'll convert it to VB Net.

Thank you.
Harooney

Comment: It's not clear if you should call the `AutoRead_Run()` function, the description is badly formatted and seams incomplete

Comment: Looks like `pData` should be declared as `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] ByRef pData As String`. Also if `fp` is a local variable (in a function, and not a field of a class), you need to use `GC.KeepAlive(fp)` after the last possible usage of the callback.